# Access method from AsyncTask

Tags: android

The problem in my app is that handler doesnt work it throws this error:

```
04-11 10:00:22.090: E/AndroidRuntime(2928): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
04-11 10:00:22.090: E/AndroidRuntime(2928): Process: com.wunderlist.slidinglayersample, PID: 2928
04-11 10:00:22.090: E/AndroidRuntime(2928): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
04-11 10:00:22.090: E/AndroidRuntime(2928):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
04-11 10:00:22.090: E/AndroidRuntime(2928):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
04-11 10:00:22.090: E/AndroidRuntime(2928):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
04-11 10:00:22.090: E/AndroidRuntime(2928):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
04-11 10:00:22.090: E/AndroidRuntime(2928):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
04-11 10:00:22.090: E/AndroidRuntime(2928):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
04-11 10:00:22.090: E/AndroidRuntime(2928):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
04-11 10:00:22.090: E/AndroidRuntime(2928):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
04-11 10:00:22.090: E/AndroidRuntime(2928): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
04-11 10:00:22.090: E/AndroidRuntime(2928):     at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:200)
04-11 10:00:22.090: E/AndroidRuntime(2928):     at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:114)
04-11 10:00:22.090: E/AndroidRuntime(2928):     at com.wunderlist.slidinglayersample.AddEvent$DownloadFilesTask$GeocoderHandler.<init>(AddEvent.java:152)
04-11 10:00:22.090: E/AndroidRuntime(2928):     at com.wunderlist.slidinglayersample.AddEvent$DownloadFilesTask$GeocoderHandler.<init>(AddEvent.java:152)
04-11 10:00:22.090: E/AndroidRuntime(2928):     at com.wunderlist.slidinglayersample.AddEvent$DownloadFilesTask.viedotGeoCoo(AddEvent.java:139)
04-11 10:00:22.090: E/AndroidRuntime(2928):     at com.wunderlist.slidinglayersample.AddEvent$DownloadFilesTask.doInBackground(AddEvent.java:105)
04-11 10:00:22.090: E/AndroidRuntime(2928):     at com.wunderlist.slidinglayersample.AddEvent$DownloadFilesTask.doInBackground(AddEvent.java:102)
04-11 10:00:22.090: E/AndroidRuntime(2928):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
04-11 10:00:22.090: E/AndroidRuntime(2928):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
```

I have debugged the code and it stop when it generates `GeocodingLocation` You can see it in code here:

```
public class AddEvent extends Activity {
    Button addressButton, timeButton;
    TextView addressTV;
    TextView latLongTV, longCo, textView4;
    EditText editNosaukums;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.add_event);

        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

        addressTV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.addressTV);
        latLongTV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.latLongTV);
        longCo = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.longCo);
        textView4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);

        addressButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addressButton);
        addressButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {


                switch (view.getId()) {
                    case R.id.addressButton:
                        DownloadFilesTask task=new DownloadFilesTask();
                        task.execute((Void[])null);
                        break;
                }

            }
        });
    }

    private class DownloadFilesTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... urls) {

            viedotGeoCoo();
            return null;
        }

        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... progress) {

        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(AddEvent.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }


        private void viedotGeoCoo() {

            EditText editValsts = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editValsts);
            EditText editPilseta = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editPilseta);
            EditText editIelaNr = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editIelaNr);

            String valsts = editValsts.getText().toString();
            String pilseta = editPilseta.getText().toString();
            String ielanr = editIelaNr.getText().toString();

            //EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.addressET);//sheit
            //String address = editText.getText().toString();
            String address = valsts + " "+ pilseta + " " + ielanr;

            Log.e("ADD_EVENT", "HANDLER SAAKAS");

            GeocodingLocation locationAddress = new GeocodingLocation();
            locationAddress.getAddressFromLocation(address,
                    getApplicationContext(), new GeocoderHandler());//jadublice jaataisa speciala klase



            GeocodingLocationLat locationAddressLat = new GeocodingLocationLat();
            locationAddressLat.getAddressFromLocation(address,
                    getApplicationContext(), new GeocoderHandlerLat());//jadublice jaataisa speciala klase

            Log.e("ADD_EVENT", "GEO GENEREETS");

        }

        //sanjem stringu no com.wunderlist.slidinglayersample.GeocodingLocation.java
        private class GeocoderHandler extends Handler {
            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message message) {
                String locationAddressLong;
                switch (message.what) {
                    case 1:
                        Bundle bundle = message.getData();
                        locationAddressLong = bundle.getString("address");

                        break;
                    default:
                        locationAddressLong = "1";
                }
                //  latLongTV.setText(locationAddressLong);

            }
        }

        private class GeocoderHandlerLat extends Handler {
            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message message) {
                String  locationAddressLat;
                switch (message.what) {
                    case 1:

                        Bundle bundleLat = message.getData();
                        locationAddressLat = bundleLat.getString("addressLat");
                        break;
                    default:
                        locationAddressLat = "1";
                }
                // longCo.setText(locationAddressLat);

            }

        }
    }

}
```

I dont know what is happening anymore because my app does not work properly out `doInBackground` method. Do you have any ideas how to fix my problem?

Comment: have u calling any Toast message in Asyank task

Comment: No have not done that

Comment: why u use this StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

Comment: also post asyank task

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to create a handler (GeocoderHandler) inside a worker thread (doInBackground() of task). But by default, there's no looper associated with a worker thread. Hence, you're getting the exception.

A workaround for the problem would be to create a looper inside the worker thread, and then create the handler.

Use looper.prepare and looper.loop methods to create a looper and loop inside the queue. Try putting these in your doInBackground method and the exception should go away.

```
protected Void doInBackground(Void... urls) {
        Looper.prepare();
        viedotGeoCoo();
        Looper.loop();
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: I added what you said and it throws me in private void run() that it need an expression what does mean bu that?

Comment: @Girts I'm sorry to confuse you, please check edited answer and try. Let me know if it works.

Comment: ok it did the trick but now i cannot get in to onPostExecute do you know why? It works but it seems to just have stucked in doInBackground now

Comment: ok i deleted this line Looper.loop(); and it did the trick thank you

Answer (score 0):

You have to call  "viedotGeoCoo();" this method in postExecute.Because in Async task UI updation process only in postExecute.

Change code like this::

```
private class DownloadFilesTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... urls) {


            return null;
        }

        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... progress) {

        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            viedotGeoCoo();
            Intent intent = new Intent(AddEvent.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
```

Comment: Well that would destroy the whole purpose of  AsyncTask because i need that veidotGeoCoo() start first and then i would start the last method in onPostExecute